# Extract column values from dataframe with selectinput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

For example, I have a dataframe mtcars I want to extract only the column values based on the variable choices in the selectinput.

Sample code:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", mtcars),
    verbatimTextOutput('data')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
   
    output$data <- renderText({
      mtcars$input$variable
    })
   
  }
)
```

Ex: mtcars$mpg

[image]

I want only to extract the mpg vector values:
21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
output$data <- renderText({
      paste(mtcars[[as.name(input$variable)]])
})
```